# How can I watch in android emulator without running compile command in react native?

Tags: react-native, watch

I have changed my code a lot of times. Is there any command like "npm run watch" for watching real time changes and compile the code and design preview in react-native for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assuming you are wanting to use 'Live Reload' or Hot Reload.

Every time you update your Javascript code, the app will automatically update without the need to reload manually. Here's how to enable and also some notes on what the differences are.

Docs: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

**Accessing the In-App Developer Menu**

> You can access the developer menu by shaking your device or by
>   selecting "Shake Gesture" inside the Hardware menu in the iOS
>   Simulator. You can also use the `⌘ + D` keyboard shortcut when your
>   app is running in the iOS Simulator, or `⌘ + M` when running in an
>   Android emulator on Mac OS and `Ctrl+M` on Windows and Linux.
>   Alternatively for Android, you can run the command `adb shell input
>   keyevent 82` to open the dev menu (82 being the Menu key code).

**Reloading JavaScript**

Instead of recompiling your app every time you make a change, you can reload your app's JavaScript code instantly. To do so, select "Reload" from the Developer Menu. You can also press ⌘R in the iOS Simulator, or tap R twice on Android emulators.

**Automatic reloading**

> You can speed up your development times by having your app reload
>   automatically any time your code changes. Automatic reloading can be
>   enabled by selecting "Enable Live Reload" from the Developer Menu.
>
> You may even go a step further and keep your app running as new
>   versions of your files are injected into the JavaScript bundle
>   automatically by enabling Hot Reloading from the Developer Menu. This
>   will allow you to persist the app's state through reloads.

*There are some instances where hot reloading cannot be implemented perfectly. If you run into any issues, use a full reload to reset your app.*

> You will need to rebuild your app for changes to take effect in certain situations:
>   You have added new resources to your native app's bundle, such as an
>   image in Images.xcassets on iOS or the res/drawable folder on Android.
>   You have modified native code (Objective-C/Swift on iOS or Java/C++ on
>   Android).

Comment: I had some problems in emulator  , Now it's work thank you.